# How to declare the type for the input of a delete function in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm just starting out learning typescript and I am stuck trying to get types to match.

I have a delete function that will get rid of a todo item however that function needs to take in an id. In the beginning of my code I defined what a todo looks like which has an optional id property. It needs to be optional since the formdata that is added when a new todo is created does not have an id property and I can't give one since that is made on the backend. So I am stuck with having optional id properties but id needs to be a number.

This is the error:

```html
TS2345: Argument of type '{ id?: number | undefined; name: string; description: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ id: number; }'.
  Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
    Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    106 |                   <h2>{todo.name}</h2>
    107 |                   <p>{todo.description}</p>
  > 108 |                   <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo)}>Delete Todo</button>
        |                                                     ^^^^
    109 |                 </div>
```

Here is my code:

```html
interface formState {
  id?: number
  name: string
  description: string
} 

const initialFormState = { name: '', description: '' } as formState

interface TodoState {
  todos: {
    // The question make means the type for that property is optional. 
    // It can either be a number or undefined
    id?: number
    name: string
    description: string
  }[]
  // the brackets above means that its an array
}

type Itodo = {
  id?: number
  name: string
  description: string
}

type getTodosQuery = {
  listTodos: {
    items: Itodo[]
    nextToken: string
  }
}


function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<TodoState['todos']>([]);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialFormState);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTodos();
  }, []);

  async function fetchTodos() {
    try {
      const apiData = (await API.graphql({ query: listTodos })) as {
        data: getTodosQuery
      }
      // console.log("list of todos:", apiData.data.listTodos.items)
      setTodos(apiData.data.listTodos.items);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  async function createTodo() {
    if (!formData.name || !formData.description) return;
    await API.graphql({ query: createTodoMutation, variables: { input: formData } });
    setTodos([ ...todos, formData ]);
    setFormData(initialFormState);
  }

  async function deleteTodo({ id }: {id: number}) {
    const newTodosArray = todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
    setTodos(newTodosArray);
    await API.graphql({ query: deleteTodoMutation, variables: { input: { id } }});
  }

  return (
    <Authenticator>
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Todo Maker</h1>

          <input
            onChange={e => setFormData({ ...formData, 'name': e.target.value})}
            placeholder="Todo name"
            value={formData.name}
          />
          <input
            onChange={e => setFormData({ ...formData, 'description': e.target.value})}
            placeholder="Todo description"
            value={formData.description}
          />
          <button onClick={createTodo}>Create Todo</button>
          <div style={{marginBottom: 30}}>
            {
              todos.map(todo => (
                <div key={todo.id || todo.name}>
                  <h2>{todo.name}</h2>
                  <p>{todo.description}</p>
                  <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo)}>Delete Todo</button>
                </div>
              ))
            }
          </div>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I make todo have an id property be optional but let the delete function take in an id?

Comment: Have you tried `id: number | null` since it is optional, it can be null as well

Comment: This is not really a TypeScript question but more a question about how you want your application to behave. If someone clicks the "Delete Todo" button on a Todo that doesn't have an ID, what should it do? Show an error? Do nothing? Just remove the Todo from memory but skip the API call? The way you change your code to solve this depends on the answer to these questions.

Comment: @Jimmy Well a todo should always have an id when it is created in the backend so I don't even consider that a case. I may have written the declarations wrong. Is there a better way to write them?

Comment: You stated in your question: "It needs to be optional since the formdata that is added when a new todo is created does not have an id property and I can't give one since that is made on the backend." So you need to decide what is supposed to happen when someone deletes a Todo that has not been persisted to the back end. If it's possible to delete such a todo, then your delete function cannot require an ID.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to modify the code in the part where you output `todos`, like this:

```
            {
              todos.map(todo => todo.id && (
                <div key={todo.id}>
                  <h2>{todo.name}</h2>
                  <p>{todo.description}</p>
                  <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo)}>Delete Todo</button>
                </div>
              ))
            }
```

mind the `todo.id &&`  part.

Doing so will narrow the type of `todo` to the type which has `id` as mandatory field. So then you could use it safely.